# why might my .htaccess and rewrite rules differ from the suggested configurations?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching

i have inherited an existing (and very buggy) wordpress.org site, and i am having difficulty understanding the choices / rules the previous owner decided to make on the .htaccess file.

i've been trying to google different parts of it and look at different documentations, but there are some parts i cannot find an answer to

i used htaccess tester and some rules are met, but many are not
the tester cannot check the 'ifmodule' statements, nor can it understand CacheLookup on

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE


#Begin Really Simple Security
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#End Really Simple Security
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

firstly, the tester said that

```
RewriteEngine on

Only the last RewriteEngine line is taken into account
```

*if so, why is it added for each of the tagged sections? can i omit this?*

also, many of the litespeed rules were not met, but i also recognize there are some parts that it cannot understand/see

it seems like it is missing parts of the 'example rules' set on the [litespeed .htaccess and rewrite rules](https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2017/07/26/wpw-rewrite-rules-in-the-proper-order/)

why might they change certain parts of the 'suggested' example rules? ex my file says

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
```

(which cannot be checked by the tester, as the variable is unknown to it)
but the example rewrite rules includes the [or]

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp" [or]
```

also, i am not sure why they decided to include if statements to check which module?
*(is there any pro of these, or can these 'ifmodule' tags be removed?)*

finally, this may be a silly question- is '**really simple SSL' the same as/ formerly called 'really simple security'?**
if it is, should i update my .htaccess to the really simple SSLs .htaccess guide?

i'm hoping this thread can also help others trying to configure their website.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like decisions were made to install a lot of different WordPress plugins, each of which added their own section to `.htaccess`.  It doesn't look like anybody built this configuration with any sort of plan.

`RewriteEngine On` is included multiple times because each plugin wants to make sure it is set.  Having multiple such statements doesn't hurt anything other than take up space and processing time.

The `IfModule` directives are added by plugins so that sites don't immediately get a "500 Internal Server Error" if required Apache modules are not enabled.  Without the modules, the rules don't have any effect, so it rarely makes sense to add checks for modules when implementing your own rules on a machine where you know what Apache modules are enabled.

My guess as that the rules were added by older versions of plugins rather than being edited by hand. It is possible somebody tried to customize the file, but that isn't necessarily the case.

I'd caution against doing much editing between the `BEGIN` and `END` comments.  Plugins put those markers there so that they can replace their own rules during upgrades.  Any changes you make are likely to be overwritten at some point.

I'd suggest seeing which WordPress plugins the site actually needs.  It looks like there may be multiple caching plugins installed and they probably conflict with each other. I'd start by paring back to the minimal set of plugins that provide the functionality you need.

You should upgrade all the plugins to patch likely security holes and make sure the rewrite rules for each are updated to the latest as well.